# How to make a string from separate int values

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a string out of 3 elements with the following format '0/5'.

int start = 0;
int finish = 5;

I've tried doing this:

```
    char string[20];

    string[0] = (char) start;
    string[1] = '/';
    string[2] = (char) finish;

    string[strlen(string)] = '\0';
```

But when I printf I get nothing.

```
    char buffer[10];
    char aux[5] = {'/', '\0'}; 
    char aux2[5];
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", start);
    strcat(buffer, aux);
    sprintf(aux2, "%d", finish);
    strcat(buffer, aux2);
```

This is what is working but seems very inefficient.

Comment: `string[strlen(string)] = '\0';` is always useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your integers are more than 1 digit long then maybe you should consider using something like `sprintf()`

```c
char string[20];
int start = 13;
int finish = 21;

sprintf(string, "%d/%d", start, finish);
```

It works exactly like `printf()` but instead of printing to the console it prints to a string you supply to it.

Comment: Thank you! It does include the additional null-character at the end of the string right?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it wouldn't count as being a string as string are always null-terminated.

Answer (score 3):

When you print a `char` using `printf`, it's [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value is used. In this specific case, you could use

```
string[0] = (char) (start + '0');
string[1] = '/';
string[2] = (char) (finish + '0');
```

Or you could use `string[0] = (char) start + 48;`. The ASCII value of '0' is 48.

Or better initialize `start` and `finish` as `char start = '0'`, `char finish = '5'`, etc.

In addition, make sure that `start` and `finish` are between `0` and `9`. Other values, will give you unexpected results.

Also, the last line should be `string[3] = '\0'`. `strlen` works by iterating till it encounters a `\0` and thus is useless in this case.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/1TUYID)

Comment: I get the following error from that code: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]

Answer (score 0):

```
char *tosomething(char *buff, int start, int end)
{
    sprintf(buff, "%d/%d", start, end);
    return buff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted can be made more efficient by just replacing the last 4 lines with a single `sprintf()`.

```c
    char buffer[10];
    char aux[5] = {'/', '\0'}; 
    char aux2[5] = {'\0'};
    sprintf(buffer, "%d%s%d%s", start, aux, end, aux2);
```